# How to make StructureMap automatically register base interfaces?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Our repositories at work are generally CRUD, broken into one each of `ICreatable`, `IRetrievable`, `IUpdatable`, and `IDeletable`.  The retrieve behavior uses the PK of the object in its retrieval.  Often, we'll end up with another sub-interface for handling methods outside the CRUD behavior for a repository.  It looks like this:

```
public interface IUserRepository : ICreatable<User>, IRetrievable<User>, IUpdatable<User>
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetUsersWithoutEmail ();
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    // implement members...
}
```

In places we specifically need `GetUsersWithoutEmail`, we will inject IUserRepository.  Somewhere else that needs `IRetrievable<User>` currently gets `IUserRepository` because I don't know how to solve this problem.

What I'd like to be able to do is something similar to this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize (x => x.For<IUserRepository> ().IncludeBaseInterfaces ().Use <UserRepository> ());
```

I want to get `UserRepository` injected when I ask for an `IUserRepository` **or** an `IRetrievable<User>`, without having to configure each of the 4 manually.  I'd like the ability to override one if I decide that an `ICreatable<User>` needs to be a `CreatableUserRepository` instead, but normally I just want it to walk up the tree as far as possible.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will end up needing some sort of crazy logic object that will help you handle this sort of thing on StructureMap's top level - I'm not aware of any functionality that gives you this sort of conditional handling.

So you'd be looking at something like:

```
public class NestedInheritanceConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process (Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface)   
            return;

        if (type.IsAbstract)    
            return;

        if (type.IsSubclassOf (typeof(Registry)))
            return;

        foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces ())
        {
            registry.For (iface).Use (type);
        }
    }
}
```

Which would make your StructureMap call look something like:

```
    public StructureMapRegistry ()
    {
        Scan (x => 
        {
            x.Convention<NestedInheritanceConvention> ();
        });
    }
```